# Why if in AppDelegate, a property is defined, and it is not available in ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Say if we have in `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *someList;
```

and `.m`

```
@synthesize someList;
```

then I thought in `ViewController.m`, we can do

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].someList);
```

but it actually compiles with an error of Property `someList` not found on object `UIApplicationDelegate`?  Why would that be?   (and actually, is this the preferred way to pass data to ViewController?  Another way seems to be declaring this a property of `ViewController`, and set this property in the code inside of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method instead.)

Comment: Did you include `AppDelegate.h` in `ViewController.m`?

Comment: if `#import "AppDelegate.h"` is in `ViewController.h` or `.m`, it is the same error...

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to the appropriate type, since at that point the compiler just thinks it's an instance of `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`. Consider something like the following in your `ViewController.m`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)someList {
    return ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).someList;
}
```

With that, you can access `self.someList` at any point in your view controller. Note that you'll probably need to `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in `ViewController.m`.

Comment: and is this method preferred instead of adding a property in ViewController that's called `someList` and setting this property in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Comment: That depends a lot on the architecture of your application. If the array is meant to hold data that's only really relevant to the view controller, it should be a property on ViewController; if it's more of a global-application-data thing, then the app delegate is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

`someList` is a property of `AppDelegate` and not `UIApplicationDelegate`. So you have to add a cast:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate someList]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it:

```
NSLog(@"%@", ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).someList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast it. but i use it commonly enough that i create a method on my classes.

```
- (MyApplicationDelegate*) appDelegate{
    return (MyApplicationDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

then you merely need to call the app delegate from the project.

```
- (void) someAction {
    [[self appDelegate].someList addObject:@"new object"];
}
```

i feel this is a better approach.